# c warning message: conversion of nonzero integer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code and am receiving a "conversion of nonzero integer to pointer" warning by the compiler on the if statement.

I have tried numerous combinations to remove the warning, including wrapping the right hand side of my condition in double quotes, eg. "1", which makes the warning go away, but then the condition does not work.

```
if ((unsigned char*)buffer[8] == '1' && (unsigned char*)buffer[9] == '1')
{
      unsigned char colorPtr = (unsigned char*)&buffer[10];
      singleColor(CDCInstance, lightCount, colorPtr, 6);
}
```

buffer is of the type void *

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typecasting has a lower [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence) than the `[]` operator. Your current code is the same as

```
if ((unsigned char*) (buffer[8]) == '1' && (unsigned char*) (buffer[9]) == '1')
/* note parentheses: ^         ^                            ^         ^      */
```

You probably meant

```
if (((unsigned char*) buffer)[8] == '1' && ((unsigned char*) buffer)[9] == '1')
/*  ^                       ^              ^                       ^         */
```

instead.